# multiple threads used for search as you type results in crash

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using xamarin/monotouch for an ios app. In one of the search screens, i display a pop up with results from address book as the user types characters. I have about 5000 contacts and hence i am doing the filtering in a seperate thread like below.

```
Thread filterThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( delegate {

                   // Some ui code


                    PersonSearchModal.find (findstr);
                    var personList = PersonSearchModal.getResult ();


                    // followed by some ui code to update pop up with person list


            }));
            filterThread.Start ();
```

and here is the method that searches 5000 contacts

```
public static void find(string str)
        {
            lock (filterLock) {
                bool next = false;
                if (str.Length == 1)
                    clear ();

                if (results.Count == 0) {
                    next = true;
                } else {
                    PersonSearchResult r = results [results.Count - 1];
                    if (str.StartsWith (r.findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                        next = true;
                    }
                }
                if (next) {
                    findNext (str);
                } else {
                    findPrev ();
                }
            }
        }

public static void findNext(string str)
        {
            if (str.Trim ().Length == 0)
                return;

            Func<string, bool> filter = s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) && s.StartsWith(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var peoplefrom = results.Count > 0 ? getResult() : people;
            var personList = peoplefrom.
                Where(p => filter(p.FirstName) 
                    || filter(p.LastName) 
                    || p.GetEmails().Select(e => e.Value).Any(filter)).ToList();

            var result = new PersonSearchResult ();
            result.findstr = str;
            result.people = personList;
            results.Add (result);
        }
```

It seems to work very well like the contact search in mail app. However when the user types fast, the app crashes without any exception. Can anybody suggest a better way to schedule and synchronize these search threads.

full code

```
public void filterContact(RectangleF rect, string searchstring)
        {

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ( o => filter (rect, searchstring));

        }

        void filter(RectangleF rect, string searchstring)
        {

            lock (this) {
                try {
                    if (searchstring.Trim () == "") {
                        using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool ()) {
                            pool.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
                                if (DetailViewPopover != null) {
                                    DetailViewPopover.Dismiss (false);
                                }
                                return;
                            });
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    string findstr = searchstring;
                    if (PersonSearchModal.people.Count == 0)
                        return;


                    PersonSearchModal.find (findstr);
                    var personList = PersonSearchModal.getResult ();


                    using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool ()) {
                        pool.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {

                            if (personList.Count == 0) {
                                if (DetailViewPopover != null)
                                    DetailViewPopover.Dismiss (false);
                                return;
                            }

                            if (DetailViewPopover != null) {
                                _emailPickerController._searchName = searchstring;
                                PersonEmailPickerViewControllerSource PEsource = (PersonEmailPickerViewControllerSource)_emailPickerController.TableView.Source;
                                PEsource.personList = personList;
                                _emailPickerController.TableView.ReloadData ();

                                if (!DetailViewPopover.PopoverVisible) {
                                    DetailViewPopover.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF (400, 300);
                                    DetailViewPopover.PresentFromRect (rect, this.View, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, true);
                                } 

                            } else {
                                _emailPickerController = PersonEmailPickerViewController.GetInstance ();
                                _emailPickerController._searchName = searchstring;
                                PersonEmailPickerViewControllerSource PEsource = (PersonEmailPickerViewControllerSource)_emailPickerController.TableView.Source;
                                PEsource.personList = personList;
                                _emailPickerController.TableView.ReloadData ();
                                DetailViewPopover = new UIPopoverController (_emailPickerController);
                                DetailViewPopover.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF (400, 300);
                                DetailViewPopover.PresentFromRect (rect, this.View, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } catch (System.Exception) {

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Crash is "malloc *** error for object 0x double free". I couldnt find where it happens though

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a race condition in your code. My guess is that the following is happening:

- You start multiple filterThread threads, each working on the same data without any synchronization.
- When you use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, the main thread will work on the same data, which has been modified simultaneously from several threads already (and is probably being modified while the main thread is using the data as well), and you end up feeding garbage to the UI from the main thread, which eventually results in a crash.

Try ensuring that you're only running one filterThread at the same time, and never while the main thread is accessing the same data the filterThread is using.

Comment: i made changes to the code for locking the critical region as above. Havent seen the crash.